# JavaScript TypeErrors

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I keep getting JS errors in my browsers web console, I have been able to clean up some but I also seem to break more and more the harder I try. I'm not exactly the most experienced JavaScript coder and I just don't know how to solve this to prevent further issues on my clients site.

Any help or insight on what I could do would be much appreciated!

```
[21:34:36.569] TypeError: $ is not a function @ http://bolivares.com/shop/aurelio-tank-baby-blue/:103
```

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-35293709-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
<script>
/* <![CDATA[ */
// call fancybox
function openFancy(){ 
setTimeout( function() {$('#autoStart').trigger('click'); },3000); // show after a second


} 
// create cookie on button click
function dontShow(){
 $.fancybox.close(); // optional
 $.cookie('cookie1', 'yes', { expires: 30 }); // expiration in 30 days
}
function askLater(){
 $.fancybox.close(); // optional
 $.cookie('cookie2', 'yes', { expires: 7 }); // expiration in 30 days
}
</script>
<script>
$(window).load(
    function() {
    var visited = $.cookie('cookie1') || $.cookie('cookie2') || $.cookie('cookie3'); // create cookie 'visited' with no value
    if (visited == 'yes') {
        return false;
    } else {
        openFancy(); // cookie has no value so launch fancybox on page load
         $.cookie('cookie3', 'yes', { expires: 3 }); // expiration in 30 days
    }
  $('#autoStart').fancybox();
  function toggleStuff(){
  $('li.toggle-content').hide();
  $('h4').click(function() {
    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
});
}


function popUp(URL) {
day = new Date();
id = day.getTime();
eval("page" + id + " = window.open(URL, '" + id + "', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=500,height=500,left = 590,top = 275');");
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: Give us the actual javascript code, don't make us look into your source.

Comment: Please share the code atleast

Comment: Sorry guys, just added the JS that I have in place

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to use jQuery but has not linked it in your source code. Try link it in your code.

And also as a general rule I would say to you to test very small parts of the code. Code one line or two and test it. This way you  will know what coused the error and it will be easier to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're including jQuery in your code BEFORE you run this function and any which require $.  If this is already the case, check your console to make sure nothing is breaking it.

EDIT: Just took another look.  Turns out the issue is that one of your plugins is calling jQuery.noConflict() (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) Try using jQuery in this place instead of $, or if you're feeling risky, try resetting jQuery with $ = jQuery;

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not the issue, everything actually runs fine except one element (size selector) doesn't load in IE although it does in any other browser.